# Merge elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="date" data-groupdate="2014-02-03T05:00:00.0000000Z">
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:09:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:08:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:07:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:06:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:05:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:04:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:03:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:02:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:01:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T19:00:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
</div>

<div class="date" data-groupdate="2014-02-03T05:00:00.0000000Z">
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T18:54:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T18:53:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T18:52:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T18:51:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
    <article data-publisheddate="2014-02-03T18:50:00.0000000Z" data-istop="False"/>
</div>
```

I wish to merge the two `<div>`s into one single `<div>` keeping the order by of each `data-publisheddate` of each `<article>`.

In other words, take the 5 `<article>` elements from the lower `<div>` and insert them inside the upper `<div>` after the 10 `<article>` elements. Once done, completely remove the bottom `<div>`.

The pseudo code I have is the following:

1. Find matching `<div>`s by looking at the `data-groupdate` attribute.
2. With the matching `<div>`s, remove all  elements.
3. Append the removed `<article>` elements to the first found
4. Clean up and remove the now empty `<div>` element.

How would anyone tackle this?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have a plan to tackle it in psuedo code.  Try it out, and come back with specific issues. Scan through all of the $('.date') elements and pull out the ones with the data-groupdate equal to it.

Comment: merge steps 2 and 3 (or, just get rid of 2 and revise 3, there's no need to *remove* the divs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but I don't think < article > can be self-closing.  I ran into issues.  Once  I added the closures, this works:

```
var firstDiv = $('.date').first();
var lastDiv = $('.date').last();
lastDiv.children().each(function() {
    var thisArticle = $(this);
    firstDiv.append(thisArticle);
});
lastDiv.remove();
```

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBZD7/4/).

Obviously this only works with 2 'date' divs.  If you want to extend this at all, you'll likely want to add IDs or iterate through each $('.date') and avoid using first() and last().

*updated so it actually removes the div now instead of just the contents*